# Assign circular array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a fresher to java-script. I created a object and with key value pairs. Newly I need to add another key (**color**) with value which should be from **color array** (`color[]`). If the *object size* is greater than *color array size*, then the *value* for the *color* key should be assigned from beginning of color array

```
var sumArray=[{"sum":1},{"sum":2},{"sum":3},{"sum":4},{"sum":5},{"sum":6}]
var color=["#FF0F00","#FF6600","#FF9E01"];


var combinedObj =sumArray.map(function(obj) {
    var me = Object.assign({}, obj);
      var i=0;    
      me.color = color[i++];
    return me;
});
```

**Output is**

```
[{"sum":1,"color":"#FF0F00"},{"sum":2,"color":"#FF0F00"},
{"sum":3,"color":"#FF0F00"},{"sum":4,"color":"#FF0F00"},
{"sum":5,"color":"#FF0F00"},{"sum":6,"color":"#FF0F00"}]
```

**Expected Output is**

```
[{"sum":1,"color":"#FF0F00"},{"sum":2,"color":"#FF6600"},
{"sum":3,"color":"#FF9E01"},{"sum":4,"color":"#FF0F00"},
{"sum":5,"color":"#FF6600"},{"sum":6,"color":"#FF9E01"}]
```

The value is circulating from the beginning if the object size is greater than color array size.

I tried my best by referring. But failed. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
var i=0;
```

move it out of the loop, and in the loop the increment must be:

```
 i = (i + 1) % color.length;
```

```js
var sumArray=[{"sum":1},{"sum":2},{"sum":3},{"sum":4},{"sum":5},{"sum":6}]
var color=["#FF0F00","#FF6600","#FF9E01"];


var i=0;
var combinedObj = sumArray.map(function(obj) {
    var me = Object.assign({}, obj);
    me.color = color[i];
    i = (i + 1) % color.length;
    return me;
});
console.log(combinedObj);
```

A different approach, avoiding global variables, can be based on second map parameter:

```js
var sumArray=[{"sum":1},{"sum":2},{"sum":3},{"sum":4},{"sum":5},{"sum":6}]
var color=["#FF0F00","#FF6600","#FF9E01"];


var combinedObj = sumArray.map(function(obj, idx) {
    var me = Object.assign({}, obj);
    me.color = color[idx % color.length];
    return me;
});
console.log(combinedObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to define the iterator outside the loop, and reset it to zero, when it gets to the smallest arrays length

```js
var sumArray = [{"sum": 1}, {"sum": 2}, {"sum": 3}, {"sum": 4}, {"sum": 5}, {"sum": 6}]
var color    = ["#FF0F00", "#FF6600", "#FF9E01"];

var i = 0;

var combinedObj = sumArray.map(function(obj) {
  var me = Object.assign({}, obj);
  i = i === color.length ? 0 : i;
  me.color = color[i++];
  return me;
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( combinedObj, 0, 4 ) )
```

You could just reduce the array instead

```js
var sumArray = [{"sum":1},{"sum":2},{"sum":3},{"sum":4},{"sum":5},{"sum":6}]
var color    = ["#FF0F00","#FF6600","#FF9E01"];

var combinedObj = sumArray.reduce( (a,b,i) => 
  (a.push(Object.assign({}, b, {color:color[i%color.length]})), a)
, []);

console.log( JSON.stringify(combinedObj, 0, 4) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `i` value is 3, then assign it back to 0

```js
var sumArray = [{
  "sum": 1
}, {
  "sum": 2
}, {
  "sum": 3
}, {
  "sum": 4
}, {
  "sum": 5
}, {
  "sum": 6
}]
var color = ["#FF0F00", "#FF6600", "#FF9E01"];

var i = 0;
var combinedObj = sumArray.map(function(obj) {

  obj.color = color[i];
  i++;
  if (i === 3) {
    i = 0;
  }
  return obj

}, {});
console.log(combinedObj)
```